# Proof of the Integration Power Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I was asked to prove the power rule for integration. I'm aware of Faulhaber's formula relating $\sum x^m$ to an $m+1$ degree polynomial, but I sought a simpler solution. My derivation below seemed too easy; and because I cannot seem to find anything similar online, I'm skeptical of its veracity. I think my use of induction may be incorrect...though I am not sure.

Assertion: $$\tag{1}\int_a^b x^m\,dx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\;\Big|_a^b=\frac{b^{m+1}-a^{m+1}}{m+1}$$

Base case: I let $m=1$ and then proved $\int_a^bx\,dx=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$ via $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_i^nx_i,$ where $x_i=a+i\frac{b-a}{n}.$ This can then be generalized to the formula $\int_a^b xdx=\frac{1}{2}x^2\big|_a^b$.

Hypothesis: Assume $(1)$ to hold true for any $m\in\mathbb{N}.$

Finalization: Considering $$L=\int_a^bx^{m+1}dx=\int_a^bx^mxdx= \frac{x^{m+2}}{2}-\frac{m}{2}\int_a^b x^{m+1}dx, $$ which is simply the relation $$L=\frac{x^{m+2}}{2}-\frac{m}{2}L\; \Big|_a^b \implies L=\frac{x^{m+2}}{m+2}\; \Big|_a^b= \frac{b^{m+2}-a^{m+2}}{m+2}.$$

Is this correct? If not, where did I go wrong (provided this procedure is a viable method for obtaining $(1)$)?

Comment: As long as you can assume the integration by parts formula, there's no issue. However, I believe the integral in your application of it should be $\int x^{m+1} dx$ which you seem to have corrected. There's also a lonely $dx$ floating there.

Comment: @DavidP You are correct, my bad. And must I assume the integration by parts formula if I prove it using the definition of the derivative, then reverse the process by the basic definition $\int f'(x)dx=f(x)$?

Comment: I think there's a lot of back and forth here with assumptions. If you already know the fundamental theorem of calculus, and want to use the definition of the derivative then why not instead say $F(x)=x^{m+1}/(m+1)$ satisfies $F'(x) = x^m$, and $F(b)-F(a)=...$. To use integration by parts you need to know the derivative of $x^m$ anyway, right? Not to take away from you looking for different ways to prove things, I think it's good.

Comment: I see your point, thanks!